# Use awk/sed to delete everything after and including third comma on each line

Tags: shell, awk, sed, terminal

I have a file with lines like this one:

```
A, B, C, D, E
```

From that, I would like to obtain:

```
A, B, C
```

Can I use sed or awk for this?

Comment: You can use cut: `cut -d',' -f-3 < files.txt`

Comment: For Sed you could use a marker character, something that you know for sure won't be in your text: `sed 's/,/#/3;s/#.*//' file.txt`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
 sed -r 's/([^,]+,)([^,]+,)([^,]+).*/\1\2\3/'
```

If you want to keep more than three fields, something along these lines might be better:

```
sed -r 's/(([^,]+,){2}([^,]+)).*/\1/'
```

With `awk`, you could do:

```
awk -v OFS=',' -F, '{NF=3; print}'
```

Comment: or simpler `awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NF=3'`

Answer (score 5):

```
awk -F, '$0=$1 FS $2 FS $3' file
```

should do what you want.

Comment: may I ask why $0=$1, why not just $1 ?

Comment: @soFan `$1 FS $2 FS $3` is the whole thing.

Comment: I get that . But I want to learn why there was need to assign $0 by $1 ? It must be having some role in getting right answer. if I do  awk -F, '$1 FS $2 FS $3' file , this will get wrong answer.

Comment: @soFan the point is:  non-zero/empty value will trigger awk's default action: `print`, `print` just print the whole line, which `$0` contains. so you need set `$0` . If you don't,  you have to do sth. like: `{print $1 FS $2 FS $3}`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is not the same, but by deleting everything after the third comma, isn't the same as printing only the first three fields of a .csv file? If so, you could simple do (similar to what was suggested above):

```
echo A, B, C, D, E | awk -F, 'BEGIN { OFS = "," } {print $1,$2,$3}'
```

or

```
echo A, B, C, D, E | awk -F, '{print $1","$2","$3}'
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/,/\n/3;P;d' file
```

This replaces the third comma with a newline and then prints up to the newline and deletes the remaining pattern space.